# How can i make data insertions from SQL Server 2012 to Postgres and vice versa after an insert or update?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a database (BASE1) in SQL Server 2012 and i need create a copy after each insert and update made, then this copy must be updated into SQL Postgres (BASE1copy)

I've searched and found:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/

but I want to know if there is a syntax of a trigger that allows me to automate the process

Comment: if you need the syntax of triggers you can find it in database documentation, if not, you question is not clear

Comment: Yes, as @FLICKER says, your question is not clear, and it seems that you want to do advanced stuff without a solid basis. Therefore, first, I recommend you to learn how a trigger is created and different options (insert, update, delete), and what's the behaviour of this trigger. Then, with this clear, combine your trigger with the linked server to get what you want. Bear in mind that this solution doesn't sound well in terms of performance, but maybe if your throughput is not that big, could work.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JaimeDrq, I know how to make a trigger into one datatable and various datatables on the same server, the thing is that i dont know how to make one in between diferent SQL managers, that are in diferent servers (one postgres on amazon, the other is local SQL Server 2012)... is it posible whit just a trigger? and if so, how should make this trigger? i really have no idea as you can see so any help would be apreciated

Comment: You must do your trigger in the same way you usually do it. It is just in your inserts statements where you have to invoque the linked server.